# High-accuracy RNG

Tags: random-generation

I need to simulate a sample of size 100x3 of white noise (normal with null mean and unitary variance)
I'm actually using Mersenne-Twister but discussing with my Professor seems is not "very stable" for the size we need.

Since I'm going to perform it via a programming language, do you have any suggestion for other RNG? I also found [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/CircStats/versions/0.2-6/topics/rstable).

Thanks for the help :)

## UPDATE

With "not very stable" I mean how pretty different the values are each run. *rnorm* should give me pretty independent elements with are not since covariance is not equal to Identity Matrix. I would need to have a sample that result pretty close to identity matrix, even if rounded. So, is there any way to discard samples until it's very close to Identity Matrix? What condition should I use?

[image]

Comment: Why isn't typing ```rnorm(100)``` in R a valid solution?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not very stable"? Also the link you provided points to a function for simulation from a [stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) of which the normal distribution is a special case. For simulating purely from a normal distribution, `rnorm` is sufficient.

Comment: @David sorry, I forgot it's 100x3 size, but I will provide an aswer in some secs.

Comment: @JackLametta What about ```rnorm(300)``` then?

Comment: @David updated question :)

Comment: @COOLSerdash I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the variances are not exactly 1 and the covariances not exactly 0 is totally expected, especially with these sample sizes and does by no means indicate that the RNG is not working properly. (Hint: Try running `cov(matrix(rnorm(1e6*3), 1e6))`). Remember that the values specified in the RNG are *population parameters* of the distribution and not the empirical values of samples drawn from this population.

Although it is unclear from the question *why* such exact numbers are needed, they can be generated using the function `mvrnorm` from the `MASS` package specifying the argument `empirical = TRUE`. In contrast to `rnorm` which is used to sample from univariate normal distributions, `mvrnorm` is used to generate samples from multivariate normal distributions. Here is an example:

```
library(MASS)

set.seed(142857)
mu_vec <- c(0, 0, 0)  # The means
cov_mat <- diag(1, 3) # The covariance matrix
n <- 100              

x <- mvrnorm(n = n, mu = mu_vec, Sigma = cov_mat, empirical = TRUE)

cov(x)
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
[1,]  1.000000e+00 -2.250771e-16 -2.604286e-16
[2,] -2.250771e-16  1.000000e+00  6.497218e-17
[3,] -2.604286e-16  6.497218e-17  1.000000e+00
```

The variances and covariances of the simulated samples are now exactly 1 and 0, respectively, as desired.

Comment: May I ask what's the difference between mvrnorm and rnorm?

Comment: @JackLametta `mvrnorm` is used to sample from multivariate normal distributions. I have updated my answer and included this information.

Comment: I guess for moving on with the next problem, I should open another question.

Comment: Thanks, so far.

Answer (score 1):

All right, so it looks to me that your problem has nothing to do with the random number generator but rather with choosing a distribution that does not generate a lot of outliers (low kurtosis)

If there are no constraints preventing us from doing so, I would go for the uniform distribution:

```r
matrix(runif(300, min=0, max=1), 100)
```

**ADDED AFTER QUESTION EDIT**: Since you can't change your distribution. I think your best chance is to save the output of first execution (setting variance to $x$) and add some random noise (normal with variance $1-x$ This way you get the desired mean and variance while getting some stability between executions. Choose the value of $x$ that better fits your needs

Comment: Actually I need a Normal distribution with the parameters cited.

Comment: I just added them now, since I omitted white noise is Normal (0,1).
Actually, professor sugegsted me to change the RNG since that one is not so stable in termns of values...
That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: The term "white noise" means a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables

Comment: Oh well, thanks. I'm pretty new in the topic. Sorry if I was wrong.